# How to take the inverse of the matrix $X^{T}X$, when it isn't invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistics

If I have a matrix $X$ and I am trying to compute $(X^{T}X)^{-1}$, which is the inverse of $X^{T}X$. However, each time I try to do it in some computing package like R, I get that $X^{T}X$ is singular. The matrix $X$ looks like:

$$X = \begin{bmatrix}
 -1 & 0 & -1 & -1 & 0 & -1 \\ 
   -1 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
   -1 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
   -1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\ 
  1 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
   1 & -1 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\ 
   1 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & -1 \\ 
   1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 \end{bmatrix}
$$

This question is from a paper I read, where they computed $(X^{T}X)^{-1}$ to be:

$$(X^{T}X)^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
 0.125 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
   0 & 0.125 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
   0 & 0 & 0.375 & -0.125 & 0 & -0.25 \\ 
   0 & 0 & -0.125 & 0.375 & 0 & 0.25 \\ 
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.125 & 0 \\ 
   0 & 0 & -0.25 & 0.25 & 0 & 0.5 \\ 
 \end{bmatrix}
$$

Does anyone have any idea how to get such a inverse matrix? Thanks.

Comment: Obviously it is singular even without an algebra package: $X[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]^\top=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]^\top$. Then $X$, $X^\top$, and $X^\top X$ are all surely singular. If they think they've found an inverse to $X^\top X$, they are mistaken. That or there is an alternative interpretation that we haven't found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They probably computed the [pseudo-inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse).  Using the Python numpy package you can get it from the `pinv` function:

```
In [14]: X
Out[14]:
array([[-1,  0, -1, -1,  0, -1],
       [-1,  0, -1,  1,  1,  0],
       [-1,  0,  1, -1,  0,  1],
       [-1,  0,  1,  1, -1,  0],
       [ 1, -1,  0, -1,  0,  1],
       [ 1, -1,  0,  1, -1,  0],
       [ 1,  1,  0, -1,  0, -1],
       [ 1,  1,  0,  1,  1,  0]])

In [15]: np.linalg.pinv(X.T.dot(X)).round(5)
Out[15]:
array([[ 0.125  ,  0.     ,  0.     ,  0.     ,  0.     ,  0.     ],
       [ 0.     ,  0.15625,  0.09375,  0.     ,  0.03125, -0.03125],
       [ 0.     ,  0.09375,  0.15625, -0.     , -0.03125,  0.03125],
       [ 0.     , -0.     ,  0.     ,  0.125  ,  0.     ,  0.     ],
       [ 0.     ,  0.03125, -0.03125, -0.     ,  0.15625,  0.09375],
       [ 0.     , -0.03125,  0.03125, -0.     ,  0.09375,  0.15625]])
```

In R, [ginv](http://search.r-project.org/R/library/MASS/html/ginv.html) should produce a similar result.

Comment: it seems the result I get in ginv (same as yours in python) is different than that in the paper. do you know if there was perhaps a mistake in the paper or could the inverse have many different results?

Comment: @user136503 The pseudoinverse Alexander is referencing is unique, so no, there should not be 'different results.'

Comment: I would guess there is a mistake in the paper.  Note that the first and the 4-th columns of $X$ are orthogonal to the rest and therefore $(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)$ and $(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)$ are eigenvectors of $A=X^TX$.  Thus in the pseudo-inverse of $A$, we should see non-zero entries only on the diagonal in the first and fourth rows, but this is not so in the answer from the paper.

Answer (score 1):

When $X$ is *not* full rank, $X^TX$ is not invertible, and in such a case, you end up having to use a generalized inverse of $X^TX$, denoted $(X^TX)^{-}$. There are many such solutions $(X^{T}X)^{-}$. For statistical purposes, most people just care about the projection matrix $X(X^{T}X)^{-}X^{T}$ which is the same matrix **regardless** of the generalized inverse that is chosen.

In practice, one would just use a program for finding a generalized inverse (such as `R`'s `ginv`); however, two methods that I know of (for a *square* matrix) consists of zeroing-out the $i$th row and the $i$th column, and finding the regular inverse of the resulting matrix with the $i$th row and $i$th column removed (where $i$ is from $1$ to the number of rows/columns of your matrix). The other method I don't recall at the moment, but it is equivalent to what it is known as a "sum-to-zero" constraint on experimental design parameters.

Answer (score 0):

For certainty, the starting matrix is
$$
 \mathbf{A} =
\left[
\begin{array}{rrrrrr}
 -1 & 0 & -1 & -1 & 0 & -1 \\
 -1 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 -1 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\
 -1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
 1 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & -1 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & -1 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
The singular value decomposition is $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{U} \, \Sigma \, \mathbf{V}^{*}$. What follows are the range space terms for the thin SVD:
$$
\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}\left( \mathbf{A} \right)} =
%
\left[
\begin{array}{rrrrr}
 -1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 1  \\
 -1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1  \\
 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1  \\
 1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1   \\
 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1  \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 -1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & -1  \\
 -1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 
\end{array}
\right],
$$
$$
\mathbf{S} =
%
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 2 \sqrt{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 2 \sqrt{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 2 \sqrt{2} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0  \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 
\end{array}
\right],
$$

$$
\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}\left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)}^{*} =
%
\left[
\begin{array}{rrrrrr}
 0 & -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & -\frac{1}{2} &
   \frac{1}{2} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} &
   -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
 0 & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 & 0 &
   0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
$$

You want the inverse of the product matrix 
$$
\mathbf{A}^{*} \mathbf{A} =
\left[
\begin{array}{rrrrrr}
 8 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 2 & -2 \\
 0 & 0 & 4 & 0 & -2 & 2 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 8 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 2 & -2 & 0 & 4 & 0 \\
 0 & -2 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$.

We can solve this with the decomposition.
$$
  \mathbf{A}^{*} \mathbf{A} = 
\left(
  \mathbf{U} \, \mathbf{S} \, \mathbf{V}^{*}
\right)^{*}
\left(
  \mathbf{U} \, \mathbf{S} \, \mathbf{V}^{*}
\right)
=
\mathbf{V} \, \mathbf{S}^{2} \mathbf{V}^{*}
$$
The pseudoinverse of the product matrix is then
$$
\left(
  \mathbf{A}^{*} \mathbf{A}
\right)^{\dagger}
=
\left(
  \mathbf{V} \, \mathbf{S}^{2} \mathbf{V}^{*}
\right)^{\dagger}
=
\mathbf{V} \, \mathbf{S}^{-2} \mathbf{V}^{*}
=
\frac{1}{32}
\left[
\begin{array}{rrrrr}
 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 5 & 3 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
 0 & 3 & 5 & 0 & -1 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 5 & 3 \\
 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 5 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$